# Having issues with docker traefik 404 page not found error

Tags: docker, ssl, https, dns, traefik

I am trying to run 2 apps with traefik.
Both work great without SSL. When I use SSL the first one does not work. I'm getting error 404 page not found. Only first service is giving error. The second service is working with ssl. Check this at [second](https://second.ibhaskar.com)
docker.traefik.yml file

```
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    restart: always
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.services.traefik-dashboard.loadbalancer.server.port=8080
      ## configure http
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik-dashboard-http.entrypoints=http
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik-dashboard-http.rule=Host(`dash.ibhaskar.com`)
      ## configure https
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik-dashboard-https.entrypoints=https
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik-dashboard-https.tls.certresolver=le
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik-dashboard-https.rule=Host(`dash.ibhaskar.com`)
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik-dashboard-https.service=api@internal
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik-dashboard-https.tls=true
      - traefik.http.middlewares.https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik-dashboard-http.middlewares=https-redirect
      - traefik.http.middlewares.https-redirect.redirectscheme.permanent=true
      # define common network for traefik and apps
      - traefik.docker.network=towapp
    volumes:
      - traefik-public-certificates:/certificates
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    command:
      - --providers.docker
      - --api.insecure
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --entrypoints.http.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.https.address=:443 # https
      - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.email=imbhaskaran@gmail.com # https
      - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.storage=/certificates/acme.json #ssl
      - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.tlschallenge=true
    
      - --accesslog
      - --log
      - --api
    networks:
      - towapp
volumes:
  traefik-public-certificates:


networks:
towapp:
  external: true
```

The docker compose file for both services first and second. These apps are working on localhost. I have test these. The traefik dash board works with https also.

```
services:

  first:
    restart: always
    container_name: first
    build:
      context: ./first
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    labels:
      # Enable Traefik for this specific "backend" service
      - traefik.enable=true
      # Define the port inside of the Docker service to use
      - traefik.http.services.first.loadbalancer.server.port=8081
      # Make Traefik use this domain in HTTP
      - traefik.http.routers.first-http.entrypoints=http
      - traefik.http.routers.first-http.rule=Host(`first.ibhaskar.com`)
      # Use the traefik-public network (declared below)
      - traefik.docker.network=traefik-public
      # Make Traefik use this domain in HTTPS
      - traefik.http.routers.first-https.entrypoints=https
      - traefik.http.routers.first-https.rule=Host(`first.ibhaskar.com`)
      - traefik.http.routers.first-https.tls=true
      # Use the "le" (Let's Encrypt) resolver
      - traefik.http.routers.first-https.tls.certresolver=le
      # https-redirect middleware to redirect HTTP to HTTPS
      - traefik.http.middlewares.first-https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https
      - traefik.http.middlewares.first-https-redirect.redirectscheme.permanent=true
      # Middleware to redirect HTTP to HTTPS
      - traefik.http.routers.first-http.middlewares=https-redirect
      #- traefik.http.routers.app-https.middlewares=admin-auth
      - traefik.docker.network=towapp
    command: [ "node", "app.js" ]
    networks:
      - towapp

  second:
    restart: always
    container_name: second
    build:
      context: ./second
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    labels:
      # Enable Traefik for this specific "backend" service
      - traefik.enable=true
      # Define the port inside of the Docker service to use
      - traefik.http.services.second.loadbalancer.server.port=8082
      # Make Traefik use this domain in HTTP
      - traefik.http.routers.second-http.entrypoints=http
      - traefik.http.routers.second-http.rule=Host(`second.ibhaskar.com`)
      # Use the traefik-public network (declared below)
      - traefik.docker.network=traefik-public
      # Make Traefik use this domain in HTTPS
      - traefik.http.routers.second-https.entrypoints=https
      - traefik.http.routers.second-https.rule=Host(`second.ibhaskar.com`)
      - traefik.http.routers.second-https.tls=true
      # Use the "le" (Let's Encrypt) resolver
      - traefik.http.routers.second-https.tls.certresolver=le
      # https-redirect middleware to redirect HTTP to HTTPS
      - traefik.http.middlewares.second-https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https
      - traefik.http.middlewares.second-https-redirect.redirectscheme.permanent=true
      # Middleware to redirect HTTP to HTTPS
      - traefik.http.routers.second-http.middlewares=https-redirect
      #- traefik.http.routers.app-https.middlewares=admin-auth
      - traefik.docker.network=towapp
    command: [ "node", "server.js" ]
    networks:
      - towapp

networks:
  towapp:
    external: true
```

Comment: Error 404 is not coming from traefik. Probably an issue with routing in firsts webserver. Also you define multiple networks in your labels and never use your service.

Comment: Thanks, I figured this out after posting the question. I was using more than one network. I removed network traefik.-public and this fixed it.